# Applying Hover Style on controls inside Itemtemplate of gridview

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, gridview

I would like to change the background color of `GridView` rows on `mousehover`. However, it is working fine for `<boundfield>` column, but background color of `lables` inside `<itemtemplate>` will not change on `MouseHover`.

my `Gridview` looks like this:

```cpp
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudentTraining" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="mydatagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" OnPageIndexChanging="gvStudentTraining_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvStudentTraining_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="TS_TrainingLocation" HeaderText="University" SortExpression="University">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="TS_TrainingName" HeaderText="Training Name" SortExpression="Training Name">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label CssClass="rownumber" ID="Total" Text='<%#Eval("Total")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and some of my CSS Style for `rows` and `hover` looks like this:

```cpp
<style>
    .rows {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        min-height: 25px;
        text-align: left;
    }

        .rows:hover td {
            background-color: #5badff;
            color: #fff;
        }

    .rownumber:hover {
        background-color: #5badff;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .mydatagrid a /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS **/ {
        background-color: Transparent;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

        .mydatagrid a:hover /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS HOVER STYLES**/ {
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
        }

    .pager span /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS CURRENT PAGE INDICATOR **/ {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
</style>
```

I have tried many solutions but didn't work including following:

```cpp
protected void gvStudentTraining_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string onmouseoverStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='#5badff'";
        string onmouseoutStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='white'";
        if (e.Row.HasControls())
        {
            Label temp = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
            temp.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle);
            temp.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea that how can I change `background-color` of row including `labels` inside `<itemtemplate>` on hovering mouse on that row. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the '.mydatagrid span` you use for the paging. But a Label Control will also render a span element so you are setting that style also.

So do this

```
.pager span /** FOR THE PAGING ICONS CURRENT PAGE INDICATOR **/ {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }
```

Or change from a Label to a Literal will also work.